# How to setup multiple wireless routers to avoid slowdown from torrent

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, bittorrent

Currently everyone is connected to a Cisco E1000 wireless n router. Whenever someone uses bittorrent, accessing the internet becomes impossible to the other users. I believe this is due torrent activity filling up the NAT tables.

**Question:** How can we re-structure the network so that there can be a wireless network that will not be affected by the other wireless network that has using bit torrent activity?

I was thinking of getting a 4 port gigabit switch, and connecting 2 wireless routers to it. Will this work? Is additional configuration required or simply plugging the 2 routers into the switch will work flawlessly most of the time?

Or connect a wireless router that has bittorrent activity downstream of the other wireless router? The 2nd wireless router can have tomato/wrt installed while the original wireless router should ideally remain on its original firmware.

Comment: Have you capped the upload rate on the torrent client?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams We dont want to rely on capping the speeds using the torrent client because the user can always change it back to uncapped

Comment: What you are asking is basically "Can I add another faucet to increase the draw from the water line into my house?".  The answer could be yes if the pipe is big into your house and the only issue is a restrictive faucet, but my guess is probably that your pipe's draw is limited to XMbps and that any number of added accessors wouldn't change it.  So the question to you, how do you know it's the router issue vs other?  Have you tried a switch to the router and a hard-line to verify?

Comment: @nerdwaller Can a switch/router (upstream of that router with torrent activity) have 3rd party firmware like Tomato to cap the bandwidth of the port that router is connected to?

Comment: Yes, most modern routers I have seen can prioritize bandwidths on various ports.  Simply block/limit the [common bittorrent ports](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/bittorrent/qt/bittorrentports.htm).  Vote up @jammin too - they have you covered on that part.

Answer (score 3):

The internet is coming to a halt because the available internet bandwidth is being flooded with the download/upload traffic, not because of any switches/wireless limitations within your network.

I would recommend using the features of the router to QoS the network.

prioritise the following ports to have higher priority
5060 - VoIP (other ranges depending on config)
80 - http
443 - https
25 - smtp
22 - ssh

Also (or preferably), just configure the port ranges used by the torrent client to have very low priority
ie 6000 - 7000

obviously the port range for your client will vary. you could use 2000-65535 as a "safe" catchall but some online games may fall within this port range (check with your game)

Use the manual for your router (pages 29) to configure QoS
http://www.winotek.com/multimedia/items/E1000_V10_UG_USA_NC-WEB,0.PDF